# How to manage disposing an IList object when subsets of the list exist?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, idisposable

It's hard to describe this problem with words, so here's code:

```
public class Item : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private bool _disposed;
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed) return;
        _disposed = true;
        if (disposing)
        {
            //dispose managed resources
            if (_group != null) _group.Dispose();
            _stream.Close(); //or some legitimate thing that needs cleaned up
        }
        //dispose unmanaged resources
    }

    ItemList _group;
    public ItemList Group { get{return _group;} set{_group = value;}}
    public int SomeValue {get; set;}
}

public class ItemList : IList<Item>, IDisposable
{
    public ItemList(IList<Item> list) : base(list)
    {
        list.ForEach(i => i.Group = this);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private bool _disposed;
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed) return;
        _disposed = true;
        if (disposing)
        {
            //dispose managed resources
            this.ForEach(i => i.Dispose());
        }
        //dispose unmanaged resources
    }

    public ItemList CreateSubSet(int value)
    {
        return new ItemList(this.Where(i => i.SomeValue == value));
    }
}
```

So, if you start with an `ItemList`, and call `ItemList.CreateSubSet(2)`, you'll be given a 2nd instance of `ItemList` that contains some of the same `Item` instances from the original ItemList. So how do you ever go about calling `Dispose()` on either instance of `ItemList`, because once you do that, you'll actually dispose both of them?

I've considered making `Item` not be responsible for disposing `_group`, but even then if you call `Dispose()` on one of the instances of `ItemList`, you end up disposing SOME of the `Item` objects that make up the other ItemList.

Do you have to do some sort of reference counting within `Item`, and only dispose it when there's only 1 reference left? In conjunction with this, perhaps empty the `ItemList` object before calling `Dispose()` if you know it is a subset? Or maybe make a `ItemSubsetList` class which is identical to `ItemList` but is not disposable? What if the `ItemSubsetList` escapes the scope of the `ItemList`, then how would you clean it up?

Any design pattern or guidance?

Comment: Another option to think about, when you `CreateSubset` could you create clones of the items, including the unmanaged resources? From an architectural perspective I could see that making the most sense.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich That's a good idea, and may be the best/safest solution at the expense of a little memory consumption.

Answer (score 1):

Are the objects mutable or immutable, and what is the cost associated with them?

In general, I would suggest that mutable objects should almost always have one clearly-recognizable owner at any given time, *whether or not they hold any resources*.  It's perfectly acceptable for many references to exist to a mutable object, but there should be a clear distinction between an entity which holds a reference to an `IList<T>` which it owns, and one which holds a reference to an `IList<T>` which is owned by someone else (the latter entity might e.g. have been given the reference so that it can copy some data into it for the owner's benefit).

The only times I would expect that ownership of `IDisposable` objects would be problematical in a scenario such as yours would be if the objects themselves are immutable except for being disposable (meaning the only way their state can change is when they are disposed).  If that situation applies, I would consider your situation is one of the very few in which abandoning items without disposal *might* be reasonable, if you can ensure that (1) you know what the costs are, and they are acceptable, and (2) you use a dictionary of `WeakReference` or some similar structure to recycle instances that have not yet been recognized as eligible for finalization.  Such an approach is hardly pretty, but may in some cases be the best.

Comment: Well, the objects are mutable. However in [most of] my scenarios where a subset list is used, the subset list (and the contained items) COULD be treated as an immutable objects (which coincidentally also won't utilize the resources which require cleanup). Thanks for this insight. I may devise a type of readonly instance, which won't be Disposable, for these situations.